# Xcode 6 - Added Navigation Controller to storyboard, but not appearing in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added a Navigation Controller to my storyboard and it appears like so:

[image]

Now in the table view controller, I gave the TableViewController a storyboard id and class to a TableViewController Controller

When I run my app, I don't see the Navigation Bar at the top. This has been extremely frustrating and can't find a solution anywhere. PLEASE HELP

To get to the scene, someone clicks a button and this code runs and it goes to my Table View Controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

                LHFileBrowser *LHFileBrowser = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FileBrowser"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:LHFileBrowser animated:YES];
                [self presentViewController:LHFileBrowser animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Did you set the navigation controller as the initial view controller?

Comment: tried that, still no navigation controller at the top

Comment: I checked the box `Is Initial View Controller`

Comment: Have you checked it through code once ?

Comment: For the navigation controller?  There's no Storyboard Entry Point arrow visible in the screenshot.  If it's there, you should post your AppDelegate `will/didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` code.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your code.

If you want to (modally) present a view controller when the user presses a button, you need to present the navigation controller (which will contain the table view controller), not the table view controller itself.

Right now, you're presenting the view controller, which won't show it being embedded in a navigation controller.

Also, you're mixing up two different approaches, by trying to push a view controller onto a navigation controller stack, and also presenting the view controller.

**Code Sample:**

Here's what you apparently mean to do:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNavigationControllerID"];
LHFileBrowser *rootViewController = [navigationController topViewController];

// Configure your LHFileBrowser view controller here.
rootViewController.someProperty = ...;

// Modally present the embedded view controller
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to change the presentation or transition style, you can set those details in your storyboard.

*You didn't explain why you had to programmatically add buttons, but Storyboard segues would have instantiated and presented an embedded view controller for you, without you having to have done it in code.*

*The more you can do in Storyboard, the less code you have to maintain, support, and update, and the more likely your app will still work properly when a new SDK is released.*

**Update:**

The better way to do this is to let Storyboard do it for you, by adding a segue from the button to the navigation controller that you want to present.

Comment: The buttons are created programmatically

Comment: I've updated my answer with sample code.  It's not complete, since you provided no details about the buttons.  If you also support the iPad or iPhone 6 Plus in landscape, you'll need to wire up the popoverPresentationController to your button.